# Connect multiple vertex pairs

Tags: scripting, vertices, bmesh

I would like to have a script that connects multiple pairs of vertices.

My selection order is vertex-13, vertex-14, vertex-11, vertex-9, vertex-19 and then vertex-16.
[image]
And the result is supposed to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An operator that can handle this kind of cases:

[image]

The code checks:

- if we have an even number of vertices selected
- if they share one face

If one of these conditions is not respected, it will do nothing.

The principle is to identify the two "ranges" of vertices and to apply [`bmesh.ops.connect_verts`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.connect_verts) for each pair in these ranges.

If where to start is unpredictable, you can slide the index that will be choosen as starting point:

[image]

Here is the commented code. The operator menu is at the end of the vertex menu in edit mode.

```
import bpy, bmesh

# Get face and selected vertex count
# Also checks if we have a good selection
def join_vertices_prepare(bm):
    selected_vertices = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
    vertex_count = len(selected_vertices)

    # need even number of vertices
    if vertex_count == 0 or vertex_count % 2 != 0:
        print( "excepting an even number of vertices" )
        return None, vertex_count, 'ODD'

    # need one shared face
    s = set(selected_vertices[0].link_faces)
    for v in selected_vertices:
        s = s.intersection(v.link_faces)
    if len(s) != 1:
        print( "vertices should share a unique face" )
        return None, vertex_count, 'FACE'

    face = list(s)[0]

    return face, vertex_count, 'OK'

# Join vertices
def join_vertices(object, slide):
    # get a bmesh from the object data
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(object.data)
    face, vertex_count, error = join_vertices_prepare(bm)

    # no face found
    if face is None:
        return error

    half_count = vertex_count / 2
    first_verts = []
    second_verts = []

    unselected_i = 0
    # get the first unselected vertex
    for i, v in enumerate(face.verts):
        if not v.select:
            unselected_i = i
            break

    # loop around the face vertices
    for i in range(0, len(face.verts)):
        # get a vertex starting at unselected position
        v = face.verts[(unselected_i + slide + i) % len(face.verts)]
        # if the vertex is selected
        if v.select:
            # either goes to the first list
            if len(first_verts) < half_count:
                first_verts.append(v)
            # or to the second
            else:
                second_verts.append(v)

    # connect opposite pairs
    for v1, v2 in zip(first_verts, reversed(second_verts)):            
        bmesh.ops.connect_verts(bm, verts=[v1, v2])

    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(object.data)
    object.update_from_editmode()
    
    return 'OK'

def main(context, slide):
    return join_vertices(context.active_object, slide)

class JoinOppositeVertices(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.join_opposite_vertices"
    bl_label = "Join opposite vertices"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    slide: bpy.props.IntProperty( min = 0, soft_min = 0 )

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        active_obj = context.active_object
        return active_obj is not None and active_obj.mode == 'EDIT'

    def execute(self, context):
        result = main(context, self.slide)
        if result != 'OK':
            message = ''
            if result == 'ODD':
                message = 'An even number of vertices is needed'
            elif result == 'FACE':
                message = 'Vertices must share one face'
            elif result == 'UNSELECTED':
                message = 'At least one vertex of the face must be unselected'
            self.report({'INFO'}, message)
        return {'FINISHED'}

def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(JoinOppositeVertices.bl_idname, text=JoinOppositeVertices.bl_label)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(JoinOppositeVertices)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_vertices.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(JoinOppositeVertices)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_vertices.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: So far very good, the only thing I would like to remove the check if the vertices share the same face. Sometimes you need to connect vertex pairs that do not share a face but I was not able to do it myself

Comment: That can make it much more complicated... if not the same face, I don't think there is some rules that can indicate in which way (through which faces) the junction should be done (?)

Comment: Give it a try manually using the J key.

Comment: A script that I used some time ago just used the Blender internal bpy.ops.mesh.vert_connect_path() for that and I was able to work with that

Comment: FYI, bpy.ops.mesh.vert_connect_path() is what is called with the J key. Testing it manually on simple cubes does not leads to good or predictable results. That's why I did no enhancement of the script for now.

Comment: I do not run into any problems using bpy.ops.mesh.vert_connect_path() thats why I asked for a solution with this function

Answer (score 1):

OP here. I eventually figured it out:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

def connect_vertex_pairs():
    # Get the active object
    obj = bpy.context.active_object
    
    #Check if the object is a mesh
    if obj and obj.type == 'MESH':        
        #Get the mesh data
        mesh = bpy.context.edit_object.data
        
        #Create a BMesh
        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(mesh)
        
        #Get selected vertices
        selectedVertices = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]

        #Save selected vertices in selection order
        history = []
        for i in bm.select_history:
            history.append(i)
        
        for i in range(0, len(history), 2):
            #deselect all vertices
            for vertex in bm.verts:
                vertex.select = False
            # Connect selected vertex pairs
            for vertex in bm.verts:
                if vertex.index == history[i].index:
                    vertex.select = True
                if vertex.index == history[i + 1].index:
                    vertex.select = True

            bpy.ops.mesh.vert_connect_path()
            bmesh.update_edit_mesh(mesh)

        #restore selection
        for i in range(len(selectedVertices)):
            for vertex in bm.verts:
                if vertex.index == selectedVertices[i].index:
                    vertex.select = True

        #restore active
        bm.select_history.add(history[-1])


connect_vertex_pairs()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer. And by the way thanks also for the bounty (that was not an obligation)!

Answer (score -1):

I assume you make the initial selection manually in the correct order.

If that's the case you don't need a script to perform this connection.
You need two sequential **Mesh** operations in **Edit Mode**:

- ***Vertex - >*** **Connect Vertex Path** **(J)** to connect the vertices in the order of selection and
- ***Face - >*** **Tris to Quads** **(Alt J)** to join triangles into quads.

If you still need to perform this process by running a script you could use this simple script:

```
'''
Connect vertices with edges based on manual selection sequence
and perform pair-wise convertion of triangles to quads
'''

import bpy

# Make sure you have a 3D View window visible with the object
# selected - preferrably in Edit mode

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.vert_connect_path()
        bpy.ops.mesh.tris_convert_to_quads()
```

Note, that it is not a fool-proof script, just the bare minimum helper script.
If you execute it on different objects and situations it may raise an error.